# How to use postMessage with the ionic in-app-browser plugin?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, iframe, inappbrowser, postmessage

Since the version 3.1.0-dev of the [Cordova in-app-browser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) module, it appears that we can use the postMessage API in the following way:

```js
webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage(stringifiedMessageObj);
```

Howerver, after a long searrch, I dind't succeeded at making it works. It always fails silently. Furthermore, the webkit object is absent... As advised in [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/529) issue, I submit a valid JSON string. Please, find below an extract of my package.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
     "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
     "@ionic-native/core": "^5.16.0",
     "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.16.0",
     "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git"
   }
}
```

I checked the cordova in-app-browser version with `npm list –depth=0` and I have the 3.1.1-dev installed.
Do you have any idea guys? Do no hesitate if you need more information. :-)

EDIT: I would like to send data from the iframe to my "main thread". To achieve that, I used the executeScript method which inject a script in the iframe. But sadly, I have no webkit object in it.

```js
this.ref = this.iab.create("https://google.com", "_blank", "EnableViewPortScale=yes,location=no,hidden=false");
this.ref.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
  this.ref.executeScript({
                code: 'webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage(JSON.stringify({foo:"bar"});'
            });
});
```

Comment: Do you want to send data to iframe? which you are loading in your app

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree it was not really clear. I have added a small explanation about that. I would like to send some data from the iframe to my "main thread".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was testing my app, I used the command `ionic serve --devapp` and used the app Ionic DevApp on my Android phone. Thus, it looks like it is not a real Android native app.
I quote the [cordova inappbrowser git repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser):

> Browser Quirks
>   loadstart, loaderror, message events are not fired.

I installed an Android emulator on my laptop and I succeeded at transmitting a postMessage from my "iframe" to my "main thread".